# PHP SQL Injection Vulnerability In UPDATE Statements

Tags: php, sql-injection, vulnerability, mysql

Take the following SQL query as an example:

```
UPDATE `sqlinjection2` SET `$vote`=`$vote`+1
```

Our goal is to increment the vote count by more than one, in one request.

***We cannot access the code itself.***

If we can send a value to $vote, we could send:

```
vote`=1, `vote`=X+`vote
```

So that the query looks like that:

```
SET `vote`=1, `vote`=X+`vote`=`vote`=1, `vote`=X+`vote`+1;
```

**Clarification:** X is a number.

My question is, how does this part work?

```
`vote`=X+`vote`=`vote`=1
```

I understand that it sets the column *vote* to be NULL, but why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The example you give results in the value 0 (not NULL) being returned. This is because the query you constructed ended up to be a boolean comparison. The `=` within the assignment part(s) of an UPDATE statement is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator as you might expect.

Injection `` vote`=1, `vote`=10+`vote `` results in query `` UPDATE mytable SET /*part1*/`vote`=1, /*part2*/`vote`=10+`vote` = `vote`=1, /*part3*/`vote`=10+`vote` + 1 `` which deconstructs to this (using == as a comparison operator for clarity:

```
PART1:  
vote = 1

PART2: 
vote = ((10+vote) == vote) == 1
vote = ( 11 == vote ) == 1 
vote = ( 11 == 10 ) == 1 
vote = FALSE == 1
vote = FALSE (0) 

PART 3:
vote = 10 + vote + 1 
vote = 10 + FALSE (0) + 1 
vote = 11
```

The more interesting injection would be to just set the vote column and then ending the query by using a comment:

```
$vote = "vote` = 1337 -- and we don't care about the rest";
// results in: 
// UPDATE mytable set `vote` = 1337 -- and we don't care about the rest` = `vote` = 1337 -- and we don't care about the rest` + 1
```

MySQL will ignore everything after the first occurance of -- as a comment and will set the value (actually, all vote values in the table) to 1337.